# How can I revert my edit?

Tags: support, edits

A new user created a question and didn't post the code, then people asked the code in the comment and he posted it there, in the comment, so I tried to help him by editing his question and putting his code formatted there but he did that before and I ended overriding a edit that he did at the same time...

How can I reverse this?
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13826716/revisions

Comment: Don't worry these things happen - I voted to reject your original edit (as although it was with good intention - it would actually introduce incorrectly formatted code) - I also put a rollback to version 3

Comment: @JonClements: If there are further improvements to the formatting, just make them. Don't roll it back to the even worse formatting the OP posted.

Comment: Haha - now I'm confused - as actually now it's been rolled back to what you originally put, it looks fine - but in the edit review queue it looked all over the place... What the...?

Comment: @JonClements Thank you. animuson reversed to my edit, so I edited again to fix the incorrectly formatted part, it's on queue. Also, that part worried me, I felt bad because I didn't see that line in the preview, only later.

Comment: Also - this is just my opinion though. If it's a simple line or two with code that you can't possibly corrupt the intent of (so that by fixing formatting - you're actually fixing the problem) - and it'll just take too long for an OP that's making an effort but struggling to be pointed to the correct way to format code/etc... - then go for out. Otherwise, it's generally better the OP makes the effort - and that in part also shows they've bothered to correct a post, and also assists them in others that may be willing to help, instead of someone quick fixing. (Hope this makes sense)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why does the edit need reverted? Your code formatting looks nicer than his, so I see nothing wrong with leaving it exactly the way it is.

---

But normally, there are a few ways to do this.

**If you have full editing privileges, and:**

- If you are still in the grace period, you can simply edit it back to its original form and the revision will completely disappear as if it never happened.
- If you are past the grace period, you can roll the edit back by clicking the "rollback" link on that revision in the post's revision history.

**If you don't have full editing privileges** you have to manually revert the post to its original form as a new suggested edit, which will have to go through the review process again to be approved.

Comment: thank you, now I understand why I couldn't find a button/link to rollback

Comment: To undo the most recent revision, **rollback to the _preceding_ revision**. In case anyone besides me gets confused as to why the rollback button is missing from the most recent revision. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your edit wasn't particularly damaging, so it's not a big deal, but for future reference:

if you have editing privileges, in the header of each revision you should see the links:

> source|edit|rollback

You click the **rollback** link on the revision that you want to rollback to

If you want me to go do that for you, just say so in a comment

Comment: i see only source, may be this link requires reputation?