# Revert editing a post

Tags: support, edits

How can I revert a faulty edit to a post of someone else?

There is no need to review my edit because I overlooked a fault; now I want to revert it.

Comment: you suggested an edit and now you think your suggestion is wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: If the edit has been _approved_ (it might not be), you can suggest another edit, correcting the issue - it would be a good idea to put the details int he summary for the reviewers. If you have enough rep, you may be able to rollback directly, as others have answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a "rollback" option in the revision history to handle this:

> [image]

However, it is only avalabie to users with full editing privileges (2k rep).

For users who can only suggest edits, the only option you have is to suggest another edit fixing your mistake (a good revision comment here is also likely important).

If you have suggested an edit and you want to "retract" the suggestion, before it has even been evaluated, then there simply is no such feature.  If it's really inappropriate hopefully it will be rejected.  If it's not, again, you can simply suggest the fix, or post a comment so that someone else can fix it.

Comment: Okay, thank you but I have not enough reputation to rollback my own wrong suggestion. :(

Comment: Doesn't getting one's edit suggestions rejected cause bad things?

Comment: @AllDani.com You'll be banned from suggesting edits for a short period of time if you have enough edits rejected in a short period of time.

Comment: Then I'd love to be able to retract my suggestions at any time, so long as they weren't reviewed yet.

Answer (score 2):

> **If you have full editing privileges, and:**
>
> - If you are still in the grace period, you can simply edit it back to its original form and the revision will completely disappear as if it
>     never happened.
> - If you are past the grace period, you can roll the edit back by clicking the "rollback" link on that revision in the post's revision
>     history.
>
> **If you don't have full editing privileges** you have to manually revert the post to its original form as a new suggested edit, which
>   will have to go through the review process again to be approved.

Above is a copied excerpt from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158366/238020)