# Missing rollback option for pure tag edit revision

Tags: support, tags, revisions-list, rollbacks

I see that I have made an [invalid edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9286331/2) on a question by replacing a tag with another. Now I want to correct that by reverting that edit.

But the normal [rollback feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210228/133217) is missing:

[image: Screenshot showing rollback option missing for one of the revisions]

I assume this is due to no change of the body text and some code consider this not to be an edit or something like that. Can this be fixed so that pure tag edits can be rolled back like just like the other revisions?

Update:

I now understand that the rollback feature is implemented somewhat similar to `git reset --hard HEAD~3`, while I was expecting it to behave similar to `git rebase -i HEAD~3` where I could deselect individual revisions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not missing - it shouldn't be there. The rollback button rolls back **to that revision**. So clicking it on revision 1 would roll the post back to revision 1. Clicking it on 2 would roll back to revision 2, but it's already at revision 2, so that wouldn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: Ah, I see. A usability issue. Well, I am obviously not a frequent rollbacker...